# Intercepting Request in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application using MVC 4.5. I have been instructed to put a query string authorization to the application. The application serves as a data processor for another application at the front.

We decided to append a querystring in the requesting URLs containing a hash code for instance http://dr.appbox.us/DataReport/?passcode=HASHCODE.

The HASHCODE can be checked and if it matches the request is permitted further. 
Now I have about 20 controllers in the application, is there a way that I can check if the HASHCODE is valid in global.asax and redirect the user to error page from there?

Also please tell me if there is a way to check if I can bypass this hashcode for Ajax requests in the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom action filter for this. If you create a new class that inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute` and override the `OnActionExecuting` method. Here you can validate the passcode and redirect if required.

```
public class HashCodeCheckFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var passcode = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["passcode"];
        // Validate passcode
        var valid = false;

        // If invalid then do some error processing
        if (!valid)
        {
            // Redirect to errro page....
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult("NameOfErrorRoute");
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

You can then either use this on specific controllers / actions as an attribute:

```
[HashCodeCheckFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    [HashCodeCheckFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Or you can register it in `Application_Start` (Or `App_Start`/`FilterConfig`) as a global filter that applies to all requests:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HashCodeCheckFilterAttribute());
```

If you want to not check if the request is an ajax request you can check the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header on the request to see if it equals `xmlhttprequest`.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way that I can check if the HASHCODE is valid in global.asax and redirect the user to error page from there

I would use a [`HttpHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler(v=vs.110).aspx) which is better suitable for this. (See documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675(v=vs.100).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.140).aspx) and step-by-step tutorial [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001))

> Also please tell me if there is a way to check if I can bypass this hashcode for Ajax requests in the application.

You could check if the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-requested-with"]` is `XMLHttpRequest`. Then it is an AJAX call and you could skip the authentication step. Additionally, you could set a session variable when receiving the hashcode for the first time and check if that hashcode is still valid when the AJAX request is done. Then you will have a better security then just not checking it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you should be looking at implementing an `IAuthorizationFilter` rather than trying to use Global.asax.  An implementation of `IAuthorizationFilter` will run before any request and you can choose what to do if the hashcode in invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using asp.net MVC I would look at global action filters within your application.  You can register an action filter as a global action filter through your global.asax.

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyActionFilterAttribute());
```

Within your action filter you can put the code to check for your hash, this will get executed each time any of your actions are called on the controllers.

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            // CHECK HASH HERE
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Check out these resources for more information

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.globalfiltercollection(v=vs.98).aspx